# MudTable with MudTablePager ServerData method firing twice when changing RowsPerPage

Tags: c#, blazor, .net-8.0, mudblazor

Im facing this strange behavior from the MudTable/MudTablePager that it fires the server data twice when I change the RowsPerPage option, but this happens only when the current page been displayed it is not the first one, so:

If im in the first page and change the rows per page from 10 to 50, the function fire one time.
If im in the second page and change the row per page from 10 to 50, or from 50 to 10 etc.. the function fires twice...

Im I missing something ?

Example on trymudblazor with dummy data:
https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/GYGyOdErecJwVzbB

Issue ticket on their github:
https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/issues/8298

MudVersion v6.17.0

```
<MudTable @ref="@_Mudtable" ServerData="@(new Func<TableState, Task<TableData<UsuarioTela>>>(ServerReload))" Hover="true" Breakpoint="Breakpoint.Sm" Striped="true" LoadingProgressColor="Color.Info">
    <HeaderContent>
        <MudTh></MudTh>
        <MudTh>Código</MudTh>
        <MudTh>Nome</MudTh>
        <MudTh>Ativo</MudTh>
        <MudTh></MudTh>
    </HeaderContent>
    <RowTemplate>
        <MudTd style="width: 50px;">                        
            <MudIconButton Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.DeleteForever" @onclick="@(() => Delete(context.id))" aria-label="Excluir" Color="Color.Error"></MudIconButton>
        </MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Código">@context.cod</MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Nome">@context.nome</MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Ativo">@context.descFlgAtivo</MudTd>
        <MudTd>
            <MudButton Variant="Variant.Outlined" Size="Size.Small" Color="Color.Primary">Editar</MudButton>
        </MudTd>
    </RowTemplate>
    <NoRecordsContent>
        <MudText>Nenhum registro encontrado</MudText>
    </NoRecordsContent>
    <LoadingContent>
        <MudText>Carregando...</MudText>
    </LoadingContent>
    <PagerContent>
            <MudTablePager PageSizeOptions="new int[] { 10, 25, 50, 100, 500 }" RowsPerPageString="Total de linhas:" HorizontalAlignment="HorizontalAlignment.Center" />
    </PagerContent>
</MudTable>
```

And here the function

```
    private async Task<TableData<UsuarioTela>> ServerReload(TableState state)
    {
        UsuarioLigacao usrL = new UsuarioLigacao();
        lstUsr = await usrL.preencheLista2Async(null, null, state.Page * state.PageSize, state.PageSize);
        totalRows = usrL.totalLinhas;

        return new TableData<UsuarioTela>() { TotalItems = totalRows, Items = lstUsr };
    }
```

I was expecting that the function would only fire once

Comment: It is reproduceabel with the example on mudblazor. https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/mYmoEROBQyquMUDA . I see you already comitted an issue ticket on their github https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/issues/8298 . Can you maybe include the link in your question?

Comment: Hi ! Updated the question with a link to trymudblazor using dummy data and add the link to the issue on github.